# Magic Mouse has issues staying connected

Tags: bluetooth, magic-mouse

I have an Apple Magic Mouse 1. Works perfect on the Mac full batteries as well.

It connects to my bluetooth, works perfectly for few mins, disconnects and then after 15 secs reconnects. Tried it on 2 seperate kubuntu installs same result.

Ive disabled /sys/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_esco still nothing

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:        22.10
Codename:       kinetic
```

Any thoughts.

here is bluetoothctl.

```
Controller E0:D0:45:AF:E1:63 (public)
        Name: cactus
        Alias: cactus
        Class: 0x007c0100
        Powered: yes
        Discoverable: no
        DiscoverableTimeout: 0x000000b4
        Pairable: yes
        UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
        UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0541
        Discovering: no
        Roles: central
        Roles: peripheral
Advertising Features:
        ActiveInstances: 0x00 (0)
        SupportedInstances: 0x0c (12)
        SupportedIncludes: tx-power
        SupportedIncludes: appearance
        SupportedIncludes: local-name
        SupportedSecondaryChannels: 1M
        SupportedSecondaryChannels: 2M
        SupportedSecondaryChannels: Coded
```

Comment: I had similar issues with an Apple Magic Mouse on a non-Apple Ubuntu machine, it was [the bluetooth interfering with the Wi-Fi](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/466800/183983). If I would just turn the Wi-Fi off, it would work without problems. I ended up switching to a Logitech touch mouse.

Comment: You can try to change the band (frequency) of your Wi-Fi, if this is a possibility for you.

Comment: I love the MM. Nothing like it out there. They all have physical scroll wheels which I find annoying in the days of touch pads especially if you want to do left-right scrolls.Also most require dongles.  But wifi  is a good clue. Are you using an MM 1 or 2? I just ordered some Amazon generic no dongleless. Lets see if that works.  Anyone else with clues?

Comment: Agree with you 100 %, I cannot understand how in 2023 there are still so many "mechanic wheel" mice and so few touch mice out there. I was using a Magic Mouse 2 if I recall correctly. After doing some research I acquired a Logitech T400, which I actually like it more than the MM. The only issue is that it is really hard to get as it is not manufactured anymore (only second hand). But is fantastic, and more comfortable to the hand too. Sorry I cannot be of more help. In my case I could not change the Wi-Fi frequency from my hotspot so I was forced to go for other solution.

Comment: There is another alternative, which is the Logitech M600, more similar to the MM. Also very hard to find, I also got one (second hand). It is nice, but I ended up liking more the T400. Both Logitech have not a single issue with connectivity or interference with the Wi-Fi or anything. They just work. Thought they need a bit of configuration.